# How to transform if elif to getopts

Tags: bash, if-statement, getopt, getopts

i've been working on transforming if elif statement to getopts for sometime but i can't seems to get it. I would like to run getopts statement without inserting any options.

```
if [ $? eq 0 ]; then
    echo "username exist"
    exit 1
elif grep $uid  
    echo"$uid"
elif grep $gid
     echo"$gid"
```

might be some stupid question, but yeah. just started learning with bash. Thanks for your patients.

Comment: Your code snippet isn't works, so hard to transfrom to getopts... (or very  easy, like: `getopts 'arg:';case $opt ... esac`

Comment: `getopts` cannot run commands as its evaluation step so you cannot translate that to `getopts`. (Above and beyond what @jm666 indicates about that snippet not being legal shell as written.)

Comment: how about getopt with a whileloop does it works like that?

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- forget about getopts. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: verify username exist, then verify uid and gid i shorten the code for grep $uid and $gid for easier to view.